# POST data from browser not sending authentication header

Tags: http, authentication, post, browser

I'm writing small static web pages to let the user upload files to server. But I want to verify the authentications with username:passwaord. I write the index page like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Upload to root FS</title></head>
<body><h1>Select files to upload.</h1>
<form name="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
<input type="file" name="file"> <br>
<input type="submit" formaction="/upload" formmethod="post" name="submit">
</form></body>
</html>
```

this page is protected by the username:password of upload:upload. So when the browser is at this page, it has already recorded the authentication info.

My problem is, when the browser submit the file to server, it **does not** contain the authentication header in the HTTP headers and will **ignore** the 401 response. Both IE and Chrome has the same behavior. Is there any spec for this? I searched on the w3cschool and Googled a lot but still could not find the answer.

BTW, how do you do authentication in the POST request from a browser? My server is an embedded device and there is only limited resource. Is there any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually a web server uses cookie to do authentication, it plants cookie while you login with username/password and after that your browser will attach cookies automatically for each conversation with the same server, so you don't have to worry about authentication issue.